# Uploading edited code for Arducopter

Tags: arduino, quadcopter, microcontroller, ardupilot

I'm attempting to customise some code for my DIY pentacopter frame.

To that end, i've modified the some existing code, and saved it under AP_MotorPenta.cpp and AP_MotorsPenta.h . I'm currently trying to upload the code onto my flight controller, but am currently unable to do so due to the following problems.

Problems

Unable to upload to my APM 2.6    ( #1)
Unable to select my pentacopter frame.    (#2)

Problem (#1)

I've saved my customised files in the AP_Motors library, and have compiled the Arducopter 3.2 code in ArduPilot-Arduino-1.0.3-gcc-4.8.2-windows , after which i upload it using mission planner. However, when i am uploading the hex file, i get the following error

> "Uploaded Succeeded, but verify failed : exp E2 got 60 at 245760"

However, when i try uploading it directly from the modified Arduino IDE, i get a series of warnings , followed by the messages

> avrdude:verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x3c000 0x60 !=
>   0xe2 avrdude: verification error; content mismatch

followed by the message

> " avrdude done.Thank you. "

Does this mean that the uploading of the firmware to my flight controller is successfull? Also, is there any difference between uploading via mission planner and the modified Arduino IDE?

Problem #2

In the mission planner, originally there is the option to choose one of several frames, (i.e Quad/HexaOcto) etc. After uploading my firmware, how would i go about selecting my penta frame for use?Also is there any further thing that i would have to do?

Apologies in advance if the questions are rather inane, as i have little programming experience to speak of.

I would really appreciate any help i can get.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say "I have little programming experience to speak of."  I'd fix this problem before going further.  You questions tell be you don't know how to use even the basic Arduino IDE.

Have you gotten the example sketches in the IDE to work?  Staring with the blinking LED example?  Sorry if this is an insulting question butI don't know, you don't say what you CAN do

Now to your question. "Uploaded Succeeded, but verify failed" means that when the code was loaded and the read back to verify  the loading as accurate.  This failed.  So you can't be sure the correct code is loaded in the Arduino.

We don't know why this failed.  I would put the copter and related software aside and verify you can load code into the Aduino and verify it.  Just write some big sketch that nearly fills memory.